# "Unknown or uninitialised column" error in R when converting code to SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server, tibble

I can run my code just fine on my r studio console on my desktop.

However, when trying to convert the code to run within SQL Server Management Studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/r/sql-server-r-services?view=sql-server-2016), I run into the following.

I have a function that requires a tibble.

The complier seems to recognize the tibble as when I do:

```
print(m)
```

It returns output. However when I do

```
print(m$dev)
```

I get the error:

> Unknown or uninitialised column: 'dev'.

I've created an empty `tibble` and then copy contents into it as a possible solution (as opposed to copying without creating it first).  Not sure what else I can do:

```
m <- as_tibble(data.frame(matrix(nrow=0,ncol=length(colnames(df)))))
colnames(m) <- colnames(df)
```

Comment: Does `print(m[[1]])` (or whatever column corresponds to "$dev") produce output?

Comment: nope, get a subscript out of bounds error:    Error in .subset2(x, i) : subscript out of bounds
Calls: source ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> print -> [[ -> [[.tbl_df

Comment: What does `class(m)` return? Can you use `pull(m, dev)`

Comment: nope. that errors out as well.

Comment: Are we sure Tibbles are even supported data types in SQL server, I thought it was an RStudio special thing? Thank you

Comment: Hmm. interesting thought.  well, I can load up the tibble library fine.  shouldn't that error out?